# Receive POST in Swift using PHP

Tags: php, swift, nsurl

Good morning,

I'm trying to send a variable (id_post) through a PHP file using Swift and the .php file it's called, but ¨id_post¨ is empty, because when I print the value of ¨id_post¨ it's always empty.

Do you know why is this happening? I have used the same function in another project from 1 month ago and there is working and here isn't. Am I missing something?

Also I have tested the ¨postString¨ value and it's always correct (id_post=64).

Here is my Swift code:

```
func requestPost () {

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://www.website.com/post.php")!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    let postString = "id_post="+id_post

    request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        data, response, error in

        if error != nil {
            return
        }

        let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
        print("post: \(responseString)")

        self.posts = self.parseJsonData(data!)

        // Reload table view
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        })
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Here is my PHP code:

```
$dbhost="localhost";
$dbusuario="dbuser";
$dbpassword="dbpassword";
$db="db";
$conexion = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbusuario, $dbpassword);
mysql_select_db($db, $conexion);
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

$id_post=$_POST['id_post'];

$return_arr = array();

$fetch = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id=$id_post");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($fetch, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
$row_array['id'] = $row['id'];

$row_array['image'] = $row['image'];

array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
}

echo '{"post": '.json_encode($return_arr).'}';
```

Thanks in advance,

Regards.

Comment: put JSON file formate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing I had to change it was the "http://www.website.com" to "http://website.com". I don't know why it wasn't working that way, but I post the solution if someone has the same weird problem.

Regards,